# How to finish "Activity A" since "Activity B"? (Finish an Activity since other)

Tags: android, android-activity, activity-finish

I'm trying to finish the Activity A since Activity B when it will finish too. The Activity B was launches since Actvity A.

So I've paused the Activity A. How can I do it?

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7363013/android-app-doesnt-close/7363052#7363052

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may try using startActivityForResult() on the Activity A to invoke the Activity B.

And then, before calling finish() on the Activity B, you should call setResult() and call finish() on the Activity A in onActivityResult()

Example [here](http://micropilot.tistory.com/1577)

Comment: I have also seen people setup a broadcast and have all activities listen for it, when the receive the broadcast with their class specified they finish();

Comment: Thank you, you right!, the best to do it is using startACtivityForResult. It's was to easy.